# How to use fancybox to show specific class of webpage?

Tags: html, css, class, iframe, fancybox

https://jsfiddle.net/054j0fj7/

As you can see when you click on show catlinks you get the wikipedia page, How ever I would like to show the catlinks at the end of page.This area is defined in HTML as following:

```
<div id="catlinks" class="catlinks" data-mw="interface">
```

and this is the fancybox

```
<div> <a href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Broadcasting_Corporation" class="fancybox"  data-fancybox-type="iframe"> Show Catlink</a>  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change target URL to correct one with anchor `#catlinks`.

```
<div> 
    <a href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Broadcasting_Corporation#catlinks" class="fancybox"  data-fancybox-type="iframe"> Show Catlink</a>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display only part of the external page, then it is not possible to implement directly. You would need to create, for example, php file that reads content of that page, parses and outputs only the part you need. Then you would simply display that page in fancybox.